# Set maxlength of title from API and fixed price to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, maxlength, tofixed

I have some problems with the Javascript on my Jimdo Page.

I have an Javascript source code who put products with the eBay API to my page.
So I want to set the title in one row and put two decimal places to the price.
When the Price is 100,00€ it shows 100,0€ and when its 100,11€ it shows 100,11€.
But I want two decimal - always!

This is more for the optical, if this works I have an question about the Searching for Keywords.
If they search for "Alfa Romeo 4C Alufelge" the show me something like "Alfa Romeo Mito Alufelge 4C6" or something else.

eBay had an filter, where I can filter cars with this manufacture year and engine.
So it shows me only this products.
I tried it with category ids but I didn't find something which helps me.

In the Source Code of eBay I found something like " (Passt für: Alfa Romeo 4C)" but I didn't find the declaration so I didn't know how to implement this to my code.

```
var title = item.title.maxlength = "4";
```

but it changes the title of all products to "4" ...

```
var displayPrice = currentPrice['__value__'.toFixed(2)] + '€';
```

the code didn't work with this.

eBay Source Code with the Car Filter:

```
https://pastebin.com/wUiyUzJb
```

My Javascript for place Products

```
https://pastebin.com/LvRjjqYk
```

I have an dynamical dropdown menu where you can set your manufacture year and engine.
At the end I want to save this in a console and the API should only post products for this model with this engine and manufacture year.
The Price should have two decimal numbers and the title are in one row.

```
https://www.baf-tuning.de/alfa-romeo/4c/
```

here you can see the dropdown

```
https://www.baf-tuning.de/alfa-romeo/4c/4c-1-felgen/
```

and here the Products with Javascript

Comment: I think there are at least a couple of questions here. To address your first doubt about displaying two decimals for each case, `toFixed(2)` works as you would expect. See example here: https://jsbin.com/xomixefowa/edit?js,console

Comment: I think you should know that i'm an beginner. So i dont understand what you want to tell me. :D

Comment: No problem. If I understand it right, your first question is about showing the price always with 2 digits, like 100,00 € instead of 100,0 €. You can do this using the function toFixed(2) on a numeric value (as shown in the link above). Your example code `'value'.toFixed(2)` will not work because instead of using a variable you use `'value'` which is a string

Comment: I know what you mean, so what do you think is the right way to fix this?

Comment: I just do not have a constant price that I can declare.
If I use your example now, either the code does not work anymore or it shows me "object" instead of a price ...

Comment: Ive tried it like `var displayPrice = getState(currentPrice).val.toFixed(2) + ' €';` but it didnt work. The results is an empty page ...

Comment: What's `currentPrice` and the result of `getState` when you debug your code in your browser? Please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: CurrentPrice is the variable from ebay for the Price. The getState is a code from the Internet i tried, but I think it didnt work.